# Screen resolution in C# - wpf

Tags: c#-4.0

I got a requirement in my program to fit the screen on all the different resolution.
I have tried following code in XAML but no luck :(

Title="Configuration" Icon="Images/Logo.png"  Background="{StaticResource SAFMThemeWindowBackGroundColour}" EnableDWMDropShadow="True" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Closing="Window_Closing" MinHeight="725" MinWidth="1366"
                      Width="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}" Height="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}">

Please help me.. I am not good enough in WPF.

Comment: SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth returns *pixels*, Window.Width requires *inches*.  Google "wpf convert pixels to inches".  Or just don't bother and set the window's WindowState property to WindowState.Maximized

Comment: Thanks Hans Passant for reply but WindowState.Maximized is not working My screen resolution is 1920*1080 and its different on client's screen also it can change on other machine but I want my application to fit on all the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I find this code to fix the issue:

```
   public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += SwapResol;
    }


    private void SwapResol(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double width = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
        if (width == 1920)
        {
            //Code Here
        }
        else if (width == 1280)
        {
            //Code Here  
        }
        else if (width == 1600)
        {
            //Code Here
        }
```

}